# How does single session logic work on multiple sites? Asp.NET MVC 5 (Google, Gmail, Calendar)

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies, model-view-controller, dns

For example, **a single web engine serves multiple domains**.

And it provides various services in different domain names. For example, post, calendar, blog, video publishing service ...

**For example, when I sign in to a single master domain, how do I know it with other domains?**

Session ID? Cookie? How do I share a session? With which method?

Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you create multiple listeners on your webserver and assign (sub)domain to them. In IIS this can be applications with bindings and in Nginx you can create Vhost for this purpose.

Cheers!